# Question about Azure VMs DB servers that host a default SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I'm stuck with this problem. I have an Azure subscription for my domain with two Azure VMs named DBServer1 and DBServer2. Each of them hosts a default SQL Server instance. DBServer1 is in the East US Azure region and contains a database named Database. DBServer2 is in the West US Azure region.

How do I configure the primary and secondary endpoints, and what availability mode I need to set?

Also Is there any reliable resource where I can find questions with answers based on Administering Microsoft Azure SQL Solutions?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using your own VMs instead of Azure SQL or Managed Instance?

Comment: Just trying all options for my own understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the primary endpoint as TCP://DBServer1.contoso.com:5022 and the the secondary endpoint as TCP://DBServer2.contoso.com:5022.

As both DBservers are not in the same region, you need to use async commit. Otherwise delay will cause application issues.

I recommend you read through this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-overview?view=azuresql

The biggest difference with on-prem is:

- Load balancer that is needed in Azure
- All nodes inside your cluster need to be a member of an availability set
- I also recommend using striped volumes for your SQL files to foresee better performance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/azure/game-dev-virtual-machine/striped-disks-iops

Here is the resource for practicing the Azure SQL solutions: https://www.study4exam.com/microsoft-exams

Scenario-based questions will help you understand the concepts easily.

Comment: In these endpoints I replaced contoso.com with my own domain name and it is working now. Thanks